# How do I add restrictions to the Three.js TransformControls?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I love what you can do with the TransformControls object however I'd like to restrict the user from having all of the controls.  Also when I rotate an object I'd like them only to be able to rotate it on the Y axis.  Is there a way to do this?  I've seen some restrictions in the API however I haven't seen any examples of how these methods apply and are used.  So the example I have is that the other two rotations x and z would not be available to the user.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you found any solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: I ended up having to actually edit the source and removing the axis from the control.  For example, if I didn't want them to be able to rotate on the Z axis, I removed it from the actual source.  Not ideal but possible.